# How to send unsigned characters over TCP in this communication protocol format in Python?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, client

So, I'm working on a project with a proprietary communication protocol. I need to send data in given format and Up, Down, Left & Right co-ordinates to particular IP address. Communication happens over TCP and I need to program TCP client in python to send data in following format:

IP address/Handshake address: 192.166.166.166

This is the [Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYNVq.png).

Data type is unsigned char 0-255 (8-bit binary) and data length is 6-64 bit.

Data length of each frame is 10-64 bit.

So, If I want to move object at 1.0.0.1 to (23, 45, 67, 89), this is the given instruction:

Send 255 255 10 3 1 0 0 1 23 45 67 89 to specified IP address. I imagine specified IP address is 192.166.166.166. You can refer to data format to understand this data that I'm supposed to send. It's quite simple.

The question is, how am I supposed to send this series of unsigned chars over TCP in python?

I've tried following:

```
import socket
host = '192.166.166.166'
port = 80                   # 80 Because TCP

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

data = '255 255 10 3 1 0 0 1 23 45 67 89'
s.sendall(data)
result = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received', repr(result))
```

Obviously this is not working. I've not specified unsigned char and I'm just sending raw data and spaces.

This is what I get in return from server:

```
('Received', '\'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nServer: Mini-IoT-314\\r\\nDate: , 31  1969 23:59:59 GMT\\r\\nPragma: no-
cache\\r\\nCache-Control: no-cache\\r\\nContent-Type: 
text/html\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>400 Bad 
Request</TITLE></HEAD>\\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>400 Bad 
Request</H4>\\nCan\\\'t parse request.\\n</BODY></HTML>\\n\'')
```

Now, I'm not sure what to do and how to send this data so server can process this data appropriately. I would really appreciate a help here.

Answer (score 0):

Not really my area of expertise, just an idea:
You might need to send the data as a Structure.

Have a look at python's ctypes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structured-data-types

```
from ctypes import *

class payload(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data_sign1", c_ubyte),
                  ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this. But It's not working. Server is not able to parse the request.

Answer (score 0):

1) I tested your code in python 3.5 with slight modifications rather than sending string,i sent bytes by converting string into bytes

```
bytes(data,'utf-8')
```

2) Do not use Port 80,might be your http server is running on that port,
 Try to use some other port. it will work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but It's not working. Got the same error message. 

I scanned with arp and nmap. And only one host is active which is 192.166.166.166 and only two ports are open, 80 & 50000. And IBM DB2 is hosted on 50000.